# Page Loading Twice When I add jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a strange issue with jQuery mobile. Previously working page stopped working when I add jQuery mobile. When I diagnose I found that jQuery mobile is sending extra request to the same page only in mobile Iphone (not in desktop). I have fixed the issue in server side using,

```
 if (Request.Url == Request.UrlReferrer) {
       Response.End();
 }
```

Which is working now. But how to stop jQuery mobile from sending this extra request. Note If I remove jQuery mobile, everything is fine.

Comment: You may have declared the function to call web service inside `pageshow` event. If you have done so, everytime page is reloaded; it’ll call one more extra time. Try to declare the function inside `pagecreate` event.

Comment: @MayuMayooresan, no I am not sending extra request. It's jquery mobile which only sending request when I use mobile version

Comment: show some code on how you call web service if you can.

Comment: @MayuMayooresan, i don't have any web service. It's just a normal html page which work fine without jquery mobile. If I just add jqeury mobile script then it sends an extra request